# Why am i able to set the value to types in a class outside of any member functions? (C++)

Tags: c++, memory

When i run this code, i get no errors and runs the correct values...

```
class test {
public:
    int x = 0;
    int y = 23;
    void printValues() {
        std::cout << x <<" and then: "<< y<< std::endl;
    }
};
```

However as im trying to learn c++ this confuses me as to why this works, my two questions are..

1. If there is a default constuctor that does nothing, and i see most example classes/c++structs initilise variables in constuctors, at what 'stage' in the program do these variables get intilised?
2. Since it does work when you initilise them instead in the constuctor instead, when you instantiate this `test` class as shown in the above code also, how does the compiler know to set the variables up, is it a case of if it sees the asingment part, when a new object is made, it will also go to that block of memory and change the data their to the stuff specified? Is this done the same time the constructor is called?

Im very early in my coding learning so aplogies for wrong termenology. Thanks

Comment: It would help if, instead of describing different variations of the code, you just showed them as code. If I understood your question, the answer is: initializing variables in class body is no different than initializing them in a constructor, it's just a shorthand. It happens in the constructor either way.

Comment: How old is the resource you're using to learn C++? Default member initializers have been around since C++11. [C++11 allows in-class initialization of non-static and non-const members. What changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13662441)

Comment: In fact, the construction of an object is performed in two stages. First, such initialization in the class body or initialization of the parent class in the case of the hierarchy is performed. Then the constructor (or the default constructor) is executed.

Comment: This seems to cover multiple questions. [Initialising fields directly vs initialisation list in default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40378205) -- [Can you initialise in the class and in the constructor and is that correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62259278) -- [Default value of a struct member](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37369924) I am inclines to close as too broad / too many questions in one. *Or should it be closed as a duplicate with multiple duplicates?*

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes, i can add that if it helps. So in reality the constructor will be doing the assignment , even though i did it outside of the constuctor? Thanks

Comment: @moriaz That is incorrect. The (direct) non-static data members are always (except for aggregate initialization) initialized by the constructor. There is no prior initialization.

Comment: "_If there is a default constuctor that does nothing,_": This here might be the cause of your confusion. The implicit default constructor _does_ do stuff. It initializes all members with their default member initializers (which is the syntax you are asking about) or if they don't have one, default-initializes them, which has different effects for different types that can be very non-trivial.

Comment: @JaMiT thanks for the reference, im not good enough yet to really understand the answers to the post but i get the feeling it answers my question.

Comment: @JaMiT the posts sent also have answered my question, a broad question was not intended as it was hard to know what to specifically ask

Comment: Bonus reference that you might find useful: [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is essentially identical to:

```
class test {
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    test()
    : x(0), y(23)
    {
    }
    void printValues() {
        std::cout << x <<" and then: "<< y<< std::endl;
    }
};
```

The inline initialisers are essentially just a more convenient way of writing the constructor, the rules for when and how values are initialised remain the same as before c++11, all non-static members are initialised in the order of their declaration when the constructor is invoked (assuming they have an initialiser of some form at all).

Comment: There's a minor difference: in-class initializers let the struct be an aggregate.